# What is the difference between scope and query in mongodb mapReduce?

Tags: mongodb

From what I get from the [mapReduce documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/mapReduce), the query and scope parameters can be used in similar ways to filter the input data.

Is that right? And if so, are there performance differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `scope` parameter "specifies global variables that are accessible in the map, reduce and finalize functions" ([source](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#dbcmd.mapReduce)). That means that you can pass variables that you can use in the JavaScript code of `map`, `reduce` and `finalize`. Hence, `scope` does not filter for anything.

The `query` parameter, however, filters the documents in the collection similar to `db.collection.find()` and then mapReduce is only applied to those collection entries.

### Example for `scope`

This is a modified version of an example from the mapReduce [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/map-reduce-examples/).

Consider a collection created using the following command:

```
db.orders.insert({
     _id: ObjectId("50a8240b927d5d8b5891743c"),
     cust_id: "abc123",
     ord_date: new Date("Oct 04, 2012"),
     status: 'A',
     price: 25,
     items: [ { sku: "mmm", qty: 5, price: 2.5 },
              { sku: "nnn", qty: 5, price: 2.5 } ]
})
```

Let's modify the map function from the page to add a variable `factor`:

```
var mapFunction = function() {
    emit(this.cust_id, factor * this.price);
};
```

We will later pass the value `factor` should have to our call to `mapReduce`.

We keep the reduce function from the documentation:

```
var reduceFunction = function(keyCustId, valuesPrices) {
    return Array.sum(valuesPrices);
};
```

Now we can set the value of `factor` dynamically in our mapReduce call without having to modify our function:

```
db.orders.mapReduce(
    mapFunction,
    reduceFunction,
    {
        out: {
            inline: 1,
        },
        scope: {
            factor: 3
        }
    }
)
```

The result we get is:

```
{
    "results" : [
        {
            "_id" : "abc123",
            "value" : 75
        }
    ],
    "timeMillis" : 35,
    "counts" : {
        "input" : 1,
        "emit" : 1,
        "reduce" : 0,
        "output" : 1
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```